# Not able to access record in lightning but able to in classic

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, record, access

I'm able to access records of a custom object in salesforce classic and was also in lightning. But recently i'm seeing

**Looks like there's a problem.
Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID shown here and any other related details.**

But i'm able to access the same record in classic though. When i login as different user with same profile i'm able to access the record in lightning, not with my user though.

Comment: This could be because of the related list.Please check this article remove the related list to fix the error:https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000313349&type=1&mode=1

Comment: With the above error message, you should get an Error ID too, Can you Provide that.

Comment: There's no error id, it says error id but none shown

Comment: @ShirishaPathuri what if i need to keep the related list ? why is it causing problem ? Besides even after removing related list problem persists.

Even bigger question is why it is happening with my user alone, not with other users having same profile as mine.  Note - There are no permission set assigned to any users of this profile.

Comment: This is because of your profile doesn't have the permission on the Object which might be referred by the related List.So,I would suggest you to try it with the different user which has same profile to confirm the same.

Comment: Same profile different user is able to access.

Comment: Are you able to get resolution for this issue @steamyfire.

Comment: @sumat it was due to one of the lightning component that on the page was throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if you just wait a couple of minutes after deploying a new object then retry, the message doesn't reappear.